# Google doc viewer in android

Tags: android

I am using google docs viewer to view the documents within my webview, but it is throwing an error "sorry we are unable to find the document...." Please help

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url ) {
        if (url.contains(".pdf")){
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "chand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String pdf = url;
            String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+ url;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl ), "text/html");
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);


        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is free this service in 2021 for comercial or has price link?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to URL encode the string `url` before appending it as an argument to the viewer url. Using `Uri.Builder` might be useful. Something like this:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri("http://docs.google.com/viewer").buildUpon();
builder.appendQueryParameter("url", url);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(builder.build(), "text/html");
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```